# browser window not receiving focus in electron

Tags: electron

this problem happen after i update dependency "electron": "^5.0.13" to "electron": "^12.0.6" before this it was working fine.

it is hard to say what is a problem so I am telling you how to recreate

press p (index.html mousetrap.js), it will open the print window(window 10)

after returning from the print window dialog, the browser window did not receive focus (i think) if I try to select text in the browser it highlight with gray color rather than blue (before press p when I select text it highlight with blue)

**press p,w, etc... are not working**

but **press esc working**

if I try to minimize the window and then maximize then it starts working normally (selected text turn blue again)

I check when main.js print code return

```
success =>  false
errorType =>  failed
```

window works fine but if it returns

```
success =>  false
errorType =>  cancelled

or return with

success =>  true
errorType =>
```

the window does not received focus

main.js

```
...
//for print
ipcMain.on('print-to', function (event) {
    printWindow.webContents.print({},(success, errorType) => {
        console.log("success => ",success)
        console.log("errorType => ",errorType)
})
})
...
```

index.html

```
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
      <!-- Insert this line above script imports  -->
    <script>
        if (typeof module === 'object') {
            window.module = module;
            module = undefined;
        }
    </script>

    <!-- normal script imports etc  -->

    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Insert this line after script imports -->
    <script>
        if (window.module) module = window.module;
    </script>
    <script>
        const electron = require('electron');
        const {
            ipcRenderer
        } = electron;
        var Mousetrap = require('mousetrap');

        function printFun() {
            ipcRenderer.send('print-to');
        }
        Mousetrap.bind('w', function () {
            alert("w press")
        });
        Mousetrap.bind('m', function () {
            alert('m press')
        });
        Mousetrap.bind('esc', function () {
            ipcRenderer.send('close', 'printWindow');
        });
        Mousetrap.bind('p', function () {
            printFun();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body id="preview">
    kdjklsf
</body>

</html>
```

```
Dependencies
"electron": "^12.0.6",
```

I have no idea what to do! anyone suggest what is wrong and how to solve this problem

Thank you.

Comment: might be an electron bug. Search for it on github or explicitly focus the window in the print callback

Comment: @pushkin for explicitly focus the window in the print callback I tried window.webContents.focus(); but it didn't work (i don't know why?)

Comment: @pushkin I took your suggestion in count again and do some more focus and i found one hack which is working const win = require("electron").remote.getCurrentWindow(); win.blur();
            win.focus();  (for more infomation check this linke https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/20821)